# Apache Solr update without unique key

Tags: apache, solr

I know how to make an Solr atomic update based on the document unique key. But i don't know if there is a possibility to update a bunch of documents based on another field (not the unique key). 
Bellow there is an example of what i need:

> For example i have the fields: **id (unique key), name, status**. I want to update
>   the "**name**" in all documents where "**status**" is X.

Can i do that or i am forced to use the unique key?

Thanks.

Comment: How would you decide what doc gets updated to what ? Would it not be easier to make one query that would get you all the id's you need :  a filter on "status:x", then do a batch update on all those docs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that - the unique key is required as it will update only 1 document at a time. From a previous discussion:

> That is not a feature available in Solr.
>
> You can update a full document or do a partial update of a single
>   document based on its unique key

http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Update-multiple-documents-in-one-query-td4070337.html

As discussed in that thread you would probably need to write a script that would pull each document up and issue the atomic update separately.